# Installation of a Canon iP7250 under Linux

Tags: debian, printing, cups, canon

I am having a lot of problems properly installing my brand new Canon iP7250 under Linux (Debian Sid, pretty up-to-date).

I actually managed to install it with standard CUPS drivers and it prints very well, BUT I found no way to activate the "Borderless" feature, so I get ample margins around my photos.

I also tried using Canon drivers, but:

- Standard binaries won't install because of outdated dependencies (libpng12 was replaced by libpng14 and libtiff4 by libtiff5)
- Resorting to recompilation (both Canon bundle and sources from [github](https://github.com/endlessm/cnijfilter-common)) results in drivers that have a lot of control, including "Borderless", but have a print quality *much* worse than the other drivers.
- YES, I tried maximizing "print quality" and "DPI".
- When I install the printer I see two identical entries in "Discovered Network Printers", both stating: "Canon iP7200 series (Canon iP7200 series)"; chosing either doesn't seem to change anything.
- In next step I see likewise two identical lines: "Canon iP7200 series Ver.3.90 (en, cs, da, de, es, fi, fr, el, hu, it, nl, no, pl, pt, ru, sv, tr, ko, zh, zh_TW, th, id, ja)" pointing respectively to "canonip7200.ppd" and "lsb/usr/canonip7200.ppd"; I have not been able to find those files, the only "canonip7200.ppd" I found is under "/usr/share/ppd/".

Comment: Do we talk about Canon iP7250?

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Yes, of course. Fixed. Sorry for the mistake. Thanks.